# iOS Apps on non MacOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, macos

I think about developing an app for Android and Apple (think iOS is the platforms name).

My background is Linux and it is no problem to do it for Android. Android Studio is perfectly supported under Linux and Windows with all of the comfort functions (debug, emulate, bundle, deploy, ...).

As far I read that is not the case with iOS. I can programm in Swift but all the comfort is in Xcode and that is only running on MacOS. So some new hardware or virtualization/cloud/... would be needed. At least costs for a MacOS license.

Is that still state of the art??

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

I'd like to add 2 more question. MacOS is not free but not expensive (~ 20 EUR I think).

- What about Xcode. Is it free to download?
- And is publishing an app into iTunes free? Android charges 25 EUR for a dev-account. How is it with Apple?

Comment: Yes you can do it with hackintosh

Comment: http://www.hackintosh.com/

Comment: You will need a mac, use any virtualizing of Mac OS (OSX) on none Apple hardware is not allowed by the user agreement.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot build iOS apps without access to a mac. Anyway, this does not necessarily mean physical access to a mac. Remote access via the internet would be enough to build (anyway, debugging will be much harder without full access to a physical mac).

There are services, like [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/), that provide remote access to macs, which you can use for development. But, these services are not very cheap. macincloud starts from 1$/hr. Assuming you are using it 8 hrs a day and about 20 days in a month this makes 160$ a month. You can get an refurbished mac mini starting from 419$, hence macincloud will exceed the costs for a physical device in the third month, in the sixth if you are aiming at a more powerful device.

*Please note* that these figures strongly depend on you usage patterns. If you need the mac for 2hr/day only, you can have the service for about a year for the price of a lower-end mac mini and two years for the price of a higher-end mac mini.